# Graph using D3.js and three.js for google cardboard is rendering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, data-visualization, google-cardboard

I was trying to follow this tutorial for making a google cardboard data visualization using d3.js and three.js http://www.storybench.org/how-to-make-a-simple-virtual-reality-data-visualization/ and plug in my own data. However, when I changed the parameters within D3, the output of the graph was odd. It became orthogonal to the axis and way wider than the axis itself. What other changes can I do to the javascript so that it renders correctly? should I change the axis, the scales, or something else? Here is a link to the code (It's too large to copy and paste anywhere) https://github.com/codecofee19/dataviz/blob/master/finished.html and a screenshot of what it actually looks like when I run it locally. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!
[image: Large, clunky graph]

Comment: pls show code for sigmoid_output_to_derivative

Comment: @javadba Sorry I added it back in as well....I'm not sure that's actually what I should be doing actually for that function...Also, for reference, I wanted this to consists of two input nodes and one output. Also, I wanted there to be a bias node included in the calculations

Comment: Where is the code for the forward pass? It would be nice to see the training loop too

Comment: @mtk99 Hi thanks for reading my question! To clarify the training loop is the line  "for iter in xrange" . The forward pass is there as well. This is all the code that I currently have for the neural network. Two inputs, one bias node, and one output

Comment: Your dataset does not include the [1, 0] case.

Comment: @liori I included it, but it didn't really help. The results are super small numbers, that are basically zero.